# How to convert an std::string_view to std::string?

Tags: c++

An std::string_view is kind of a replacement for `char*` in C. It's a string that is not copied from place to place, just as char* is just a place in memory that is referenced from time to time.

However, sometimes we need to transform it in a string for functions that accept a string.

How do I do that?

Comment: @SergeyA If there's no answer to that on this site, I would not downvote this one. The `std::string` constructor is explicit, so beginners can be confused as why a string cannot be constructed with a string view without typing`std::string` to convert it.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot but there is :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::string` has constructors that will accept a `std::string_view` as input, eg:

```cpp
std::string_view sv{...};
std::string s1{sv};
std::string s2{sv, index, length};
```

Alternatively, you can use the `std::string` constructor that accepts a `char*` and length as input, eg:

```cpp
std::string_view sv{...};
std::string s1{sv.data(), sv.size()};
std::string s2{sv.data()+index, length};
```

Answer (score 7):

A `std::string` as a constructor for that, but only an explicit one.

```
void f(std::string s);

std::string_view sv;
f(sv); // Error! Cannot convert implicitly
f(std::string{sv}); // Works fine.
```

This has been designed like this to prevent accidental memory allocations.

See documentation for [`std::basic_string::basic_string (10)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::string`'s constructor:

```
 std::string{my_string_view}
```